# Equivalent of FragmentActvity.onResumeFragments() for (nested) Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-nested-fragment

I'm trying to avoid this exception throughout my code, even though I've only seen it triggered by some of my code sometimes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

As suggested by this blog post, I'm avoiding commit()ing any Fragment Transactions during my onLoadFinished() methods:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

I'd like to set a delayWhatever boolean in an onPause(), check for it in onLoadFinished() and then do the delayed work (committing the Transaction) when I know that the instance state has been restored.

That's fine when I'm in an Activity because I can do the delayed work in onResumeFragment(). But I have nested fragments (An Activity containing a Fragment containing 2 other Fragments). So where is it safe to commit transactions if my onLoadFinished() is in my Fragment, not the parent Activity()?

Comment: It's possible that you are seeing something similar to me. Fragment showing DialogFragment getting the IllegalStateException. Except I have an even simpler case than you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329913/dialogfragshow-from-onclick-throwing-illegalstateexception-can-not-perfor

Comment: Very possibly. Note that I _am_ using getChildFragmentManager() because I'm using child fragments. This seems like something that Android should be taking care of for us.

Comment: Bugger. I was really hoping the `getChildFragmentManager()` was my get out of jail free on this one. Are you using `setTargetFragment` at all?

Comment: No, I'm not using setTargetFragment().